# Identify number of strings in Philips 14.5W LED PCB

Tags: led, pcb, series

Is it possible by just looking at the attached image whether the LEDs are in a single series circuit, or whether they're configured in series/parallel? The image is not great but I tried to highlight the board recesses and my camera is rather average.

I searched for Philips 14.5W schematics and also teardowns but the only ones I could find were <=12W with around half the LEDs. Further, the LEDs are mounted on a MCPCB so the traces are not visible from the other side.

The voltage at the pins attached to the PCB is 110V-114V and the current is 130mA.

[image: Philips 14.5W LED bulb PCB]

Comment: Looks like two strips of 13 leds.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for that, it is what I assumed based on the CFD simulations I ran and the temperature readings I took.

Comment: Where are the fluid dynamics in this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible by just looking at the attached image whether the LEDs are in a single series circuit, or whether they're configured in series/parallel?

Follow the tracks and you'll see that two strings of series-connected 13 LEDs are connected in parallel. Green and red lines indicate each string and the tracks. Looking at the picture it's not possible which terminal is positive, though.

[image]

> The voltage at the pins attached to the PCB is 110V-114V and the current is 130mA.

That's an output power of \$\mathrm{P_O=110\cdot 0.13 = 14.3 W}\$ which is quite close to the advertised value. Some manufacturers put the real input power as rating rather than output power.

> I searched for Philips 14.5W schematics and also teardowns but the only ones I could find were <=12W with around half the LEDs. Further, the LEDs are mounted on a MCPCB so the traces are not visible from the other side.

The LED driver inside the bulb is most likely a constant current buck converter. There are unlimited number of Chinese-made buck converter ICs in the market (and some of them are sold as driver modules ready to fit in the bulb), and most of them are pin-to-pin compatible due to the extreme market conditions. I'm sure the 12W model has the same driver because the easiest way of decreasing the output power is to reduce the number of LEDs.

For example, by using 3 LEDs less you'll have around 90V load voltage. If you drive these LEDs with the same driver the output power will be around 12W. Voila! You now have the 12W bulb!

And also it will bring more cost savings compared to changing the output current only.

Comment: 110/13 = 8.5 V Vf = three series connected LEDs in each chip?

Comment: @winny yeah. 9V, 12V and even 18V LEDs in a 3225 package is quite popular these days. And yes, they are just series-connected blue LED chips. 18V and 36V LEDs are in use in cheaper bulbs which have linear regulators (less number of LEDs, higher load voltage i.e. closer to the input voltage and therefore less losses). BTW, I don't know how the user took the measurement but, as you might know, Vf tend to decrease when the LEDs get hotter. So a 9V chip can show less than 9V after a decent time of operating.